# Footstep_planner crashes when used with customized map for some (start, goal) combinations

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to everybody,

I am trying to get the footstep_planner to work with some customized maps, my problem is that when for example I designate the points maked in the second image (at the end of this post) the application crashes, sometimes with:

```
[ERROR] [1339689725.772754649]: ERROR: grid2Dsearch is called on invalid start (154 392) or goal(504 190)
```

and always with:

```
[footstep_planner-3] process has died [pid 23662, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros
/fuerte/stacks/humanoid_stacks/humanoid_navigation/footstep_planner
/bin/footstep_planner_node __name:=footstep_planner __log:=/home/sergio/.ros/log
/21710a10-b632-11e1-a3e0-0022fb659408/footstep_planner-3.log].
log file: /home/sergio/.ros/log/21710a10-b632-11e1-a3e0-0022fb659408
/footstep_planner-3*.log
```

I checked the log and it is always empty.

I am currently running ros fuerte on ubuntu 12.04, with the latest version of the footstep_planner. The file I use to load the map looks like this:

```
image: sample.bmp 
resolution: 0.01
origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
occupied_thresh: 0.5
free_thresh: 0.1
negate: 0
```

And here are the two images:
[map. Here it appears as a jpg file but my file is actually an bmp http://i49.servimg.com/u/f49/10/09/41/82/sample10.jpg](http://i49.servimg.com/u/f49/10/09/41/82/sample10.jpg)
[Image with locations http://i49.servimg.com/u/f49/10/09/41/82/captur10.png](http://i49.servimg.com/u/f49/10/09/41/82/captur10.png)

If you have any suggestions from where the problem might come I want already to express you all my gratitude in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36525/footstep_planner-crashes-when-used-with-customized-map-for-some-(start,-goal)-combinations/) by [Sergio Sousa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2617/sergio-sousa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is an error of the 2D Dijkstra heuristic in the underlying SBPL. You may see more information by using rxconsole and setting the output level to "Debug", or by starting the footstep_planner node in a separate terminal. I'll check with your map file as soon as I can.

Could you test setting the heuristic_type parameter to either EuclStepCostHeuristic or EuclideanHeuristic, to see if the map is working otherwise?

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2